# How I can check box "App Hide" checked by default in android apps?

Tags: android, checkbox, checked

How to check box "App Hide" be checked by default in android apps?

XML code main.xml:
http://pastebin.com/aPhyC7VS

java code:
http://pastebin.com/wizn2a6h

I already tried modificate main.xml "android:checked="false"" to android:checked="true" but 
but after rebuilding and install apps,I have again unchecked "App Hide" Box.

```
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <CheckBox android:textSize="16.0dip" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@id/chBox_pref_appHide" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" android:checked="false" android:text="@string/chBox_pref_appHide" />
    </TableRow>
```

How resolve this?

Comment: resembles this a screenshot apps https://dl.dropbox.com/u/30562737/DSC00046.JPG

Answer (score 0):

change,

```
android:checked="false"
```

to

```
android:checked="true"
```

Comment: I already tried, but its not working for this chBox, before I managed this and its working for other chBox, but for this chBox its not chase. I dont know why?